# I am a beginner in python and I have just got familiar with cython as well. I am using python3.7 on Windows 64-bit

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

1- I build a file `test_cy.pyx`

```
def test(x)
    y=0
    for i in range(x):
        y+=1
    return y

from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules=cythonize("test_cy.pyx"),)
```

I want to convert python to cyth but it shows an error

```
'test_cy.pyx' doesn't match any files
```

Could you please tell me what should I do now? Where should I save these two files?

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 steps to converting a python script to Cython:

1) write the script in python and create bridges to statically type C (ie. declare your variables like so:

```
x = 0 # python version
cdef int x = 0 # cython declare
```

You don't have to but this is one way to speed up a python script with cython. Then save your file with .pyx extension (in your ex test_cy.pyx).

2) write a setup file (ex: mysetup.py) that has the following in it:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(name='Test One', ext_modules=cythonize("test_cp.pyx"),)
```

3) compile in you cmd:

```
python mysetup.py build_ext --inplace
```

4) create a separate python module (ex: run_code.py) and import your .pyx code:

```
from test_cy import test
# now use the function that was in your .pyx code
```

Comment: 1- Now i created this file having name test_cy.pyx

Comment: cdef int test(cdef int x)
    cdef int y=0
    cdef int i
    for i in range(x):
        y+=1
    return y

Comment: and then i created mysetup file as you created above

Comment: from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(name='Test One', ext_modules=cythonize("test_cy.pyx"),)

Comment: Did you run your cmd line from step 3 in the same dir as your files?